# Application context is coming as null while running spring integration test with @ContextConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, maven, testing

I am trying to write integration test with spring. Below is the test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:**/context*.xml"})
public class MyFirstTestClass {

      @AutoWired
      private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

      @Test
      public void testApplicationContext {
        applicationContext.getName();
      }    
}
```

When I run the test from maven I am getting `NullPointerException` because `applicationContext` is `null`. I am not able to understand the reason. Also in logs also i don't see any error. I tried putting configuration `<context:annotation-config/>` in one of the application context files. Still I am getting same error.

When i use classpath*:**/context*.xml to create context manually it works. But i believe when i use context configuraton its not loading the application context file.I am not getting any error as well.
Kindly suggest

---

Okay i managed to load the application context . but now the iam getting `NoSuchBeanDefinition` exception.

bean file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="messageService"
          class="com.mycompany.app.MessageService">
    </bean>    
</beans>
```

Test class

```
package com.mycompany.app;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:*/AppTest.context.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AppTest 
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    public AppTest(  )
    {

    }

    @Test
    public void testApp(){

        assertNotNull(applicationContext);
        for(String str : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()){
            System.out.println("Bean feifniaio count"+str); 
        }
        applicationContext.getBean("messageService");
    }
}
```

Log after execution of test

> INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@196751b:
>   startup date [Fri Nov 20 00:00:11 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   Bean feifniaio
>   countorg.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
>   Bean feifniaio
>   countorg.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
>   Bean feifniaio
>   countorg.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor
>   Bean feifniaio
>   countorg.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor
>   Bean feifniaio
>   countorg.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
>   Bean feifniaio
>   countorg.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
>   Bean feifniaio
>   countorg.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor
>   Bean feifniaio
>   countorg.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor

I am not able to see message service bean. What could be the issue??

Comment: what is the location of your `context*.xml`?

Comment: Its in the class path.When i run the build it copies context*.xml files into test-classes directory and in the maven build also i can see this directory in the class path.

Comment: Where are the `context*.xml` file are located? And, how do you run your tests?

Comment: Iam running my test using maven build .During compilation the context*.xml are getting copied into test-classes directory.

Comment: my sense is that the context files are not getting loaded i.e context configuration is not working for me .If my context files has come error thn it is getting highlighted when i used normal method i.e classpathxmlapplicationcontext, but in case of context configuration nthing comes up

Comment: Iam using spring 3.2.2 version

Comment: Have a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#resources-app-ctx-ant-patterns-in-paths). You might be using Ant-style pattern not completely correct.

Comment: Hi , i Managed to load application context. But now the problem is iam not able to get the bean out of context. The context that got created in above code is genericApplicationContext. and when i try to get the list of bean definition types i dont see my bean. Ideally if the application context has been initialiesed by context file. it should contain the bean definined inside it . But iam getting no such bean definition exception. Kindly assist

Comment: Try using @WebIntegrationTest and you should be able to autowire the bean you want instead of the whole application context

Comment: thanks a lot guys for taking ur time out to help in this issue. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i identified the issue. There was issue with my context file. I placed an empty context file in the resources folder of test which was getting copied in the target folders by maven. And the actual context file was not getting copied in target.Because of empty context file the context was getting initialized but since it did not had bean definition it was throwing NoSuchBeanException.Now i should highlight that ContextConfiguration was not throwing any error when it was not able to find the context file specified in the location attribute. Which i thought it ideally should.I tried and put some dummy file paths which does not exists in the location attributes and did not threw error.